# Filtering data based on number of strings between parentheses

Tags: r, regex

I have the following data:

```
lines                                                                                    Freq
BrentOptimizer brentOptimizer0 = new BrentOptimizer(double0, double0);                    168
BrentOptimizer brentOptimizer1 = new BrentOptimizer(double0, double1, convergenceChecker0); 39
BrentOptimizer brentOptimizer0 = new BrentOptimizer(int1, double2);                         4
BrentOptimizer brentOptimizer3 = new BrentOptimizer(int3, double2, convergenceChecker1);    2
BrentOptimizer brentOptimizer0 = new BrentOptimizer(doubleArray0[6], int2);                 3
BrentOptimizer brentOptimizer1 = new BrentOptimizer(int2, double2, convergenceChecker0);    3
```

I would like to retrieve only the data of those lines that contain three strings between the parentheses. In this case only the three following rows should be retrieved:

```
lines                                                                                    Freq
BrentOptimizer brentOptimizer1 = new BrentOptimizer(double0, double1, convergenceChecker0); 39
BrentOptimizer brentOptimizer3 = new BrentOptimizer(int3, double2, convergenceChecker1);    2
BrentOptimizer brentOptimizer1 = new BrentOptimizer(int2, double2, convergenceChecker0);    3
```

I started writing the following script but I couldn't complete it because I'm not familiar the regex:

```
  df <- read.csv("/home/adam/Desktop/data.csv")
  x <- gsub("[\\(\\)]", "", regmatches(df$lines, gregexpr("\\(.*?\\)", df$lines)))
  all <- data.frame()
  for(i in 1:5){
    if(length(x[i]) > 2){
      # retrieve the data and rbind it to all
    }
  }
```

Can you please help me solving that?

Comment: Try `grep("\\([^(),]+(?:,[^(),]+){2}\\)", df$lines, value = TRUE)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about trying `df[grepl("\\(.*,.*,.*\\)",df$lines),]`?